# run .vbs script from excel

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript

I have macro file and I saved it as a .vbs file called macro.vbs, and here is the location on my local C:Dekstop\macro.vbs. Here is the code inside:

```
Sub Macro3()
Sheets("vlookup").Select
Range("B5").Select
Selection.EntireColumn.Insert , CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Range("B5").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Journal classification (name)"
Range("B6").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
"=VLOOKUP(RC[-1],LW0640!R2C5:R12163C6,2,TRUE)"
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("B6:B6098")
Range("B6:B6098").Select
end sub
```

What I want to do is, I want to call that .vbs script from my excel file. So I plan to create the button from developer in excel and call that .vbs file.

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: That isn't a valid VBScript program.  If it was (and it will require a lot of work to make it one) you could write some VBA code (called by your button click) which included a `Shell "C:\Dekstop\macro.vbs"`.  (But, to be honest, this seems like a very, very bad way of doing things - using an Excel macro to call a VBScript application to create an instance of Excel to perform code that was originally VBA code.)

Comment: You should first get proficient in the VBA before you attempt  to create a VBS script to modify an Excel file.  Why would you call a VBS file from an Excel macro to run Excel code????

Comment: You should start by watching this series:[Excel VBA Introduction - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5)

Comment: what i want to do is creating a reporting excel automation just by click button in Excel. I have created the macro to make some reports. However, I found an issue, that if I receive new excel file from user, then I need to put my macro first into the excel file, then run.

I just want to skip the `put the macro into excel file` process.

Comment: Why don't you just put the VBA code into your `Personal.xlsm` file, or create a `xlam` file with the code in it and put it into your XLSTART directory, and skip the whole idea of using VBS.

Comment: @YowE3K which one do you think is the best solution for my problem? actually I never heard about the xlam file and personal.xlsm you have mentioned

Comment: Check out [Ron de Bruin's guide](https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/personal.htm)

Comment: @RaspiSurya Generally you can easily run such code within VBA, you just need to create `ScriptControl` object, pass `Application` object from Excel into `ScriptControl` object with members, and execute the code read from file. But actually for your task the right way is to put all macros into `Personal.xlsm` as @YowE3K pointed.

Answer (score 0):

To make your work easier you can have a central workbook in which you will put your code along with the code below

```
Sub test()
    Dim file As String
    Dim wb As Workbook

    file = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(file)
    call Macro3
    Set wb = Nothing
End Sub
```

Then in this workbook's Sheet1's cell A1 you can put the full file path of the file to be processed.
You can even have a range of file paths and loop through it.

Comment: There shouldn't be any need to use `Application.Run "'" & ThisWorkbook.Name & "'!Macro3"` - a simple `Macro3` statement should work just as well if both macros are in the same workbook (which they must be if you are fully qualifying `Macro3` with the name of the workbook that `test` is in).